# How do I find all commits made by a certain user via GitHub API?

Tags: web-services, rest, github, github-api

Assuming that I've got the necessary GitHub authentication credentials, how can I get all commits made by a certain user from [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/)?

## Working Code

Beneath you'll find a simplified CoffeeScript [extract](https://github.com/aknuds1/github-comments/blob/master/src/server/github.coffee) of a [Meteor application](https://github.com/aknuds1/github-comments) I wrote that implements the strategy suggested in the accepted answer. Left out of this snippet, the code expects a global variable `Configuration`, which should contain a property `user` being the GitHub username, and a property `token` being a GitHub authentication token for said user. The code also stores discovered commits in a global Meteor collection `Commits`. There are probably bugs in this code, but it works to some degree at least. Suggested improvements are welcomed.

```
logger = new Logger("github")

getResource = (uri, done) ->
  options =
    auth: "token:#{Configuration.token}"
    headers:
      "User-Agent": "GitHub Comments"
  HTTP.call("get", uri, options, done)

getCommits = (user, userUrl, time, done, page=1, numCommits=0) ->
  eventsUrl = "#{userUrl}/events?page=#{page}"
  logger.debug("Getting events page #{page} for user #{Configuration.user}", eventsUrl)
  getResource(eventsUrl, (error, result) ->
    if error?
      logger.warn("Error", error)
      throw new Error("Couldn't get events for user #{Configuration.user}")

    events = (event for event in result.data when event.type == "PushEvent" && event.payload.commits.length > 0)
    commits = []
    for event in events
      for commit in event.payload.commits when commit.author.email == user.email
        commits.push(
          sha: commit.sha
          url: commit.url
        )

    logger.debug("Found #{commits.length} commits attributable to user #{user.email} on events page #{page}")
    for commit in commits
      logger.debug("Getting details for commit #{commit.sha}", commit.url)
      try
        commitDetails = getResource(commit.url).data
      catch err
        logger.warn("Couldn't get details for commit #{commit.url}", err)
        continue

      Commits.insert(commit)
      ++numCommits

    if result.data.length > 0
      logger.debug("Calling getCommits for next page with numCommits #{numCommits}")
      getCommits(user, userUrl, time, done, page+1, numCommits)
    else
      done(numCommits)
  )

pollGitHub = ->
  logger.info("Polling GitHub for data")

  start = moment()

  userUrl = "https://api.github.com/users/#{Configuration.user}"
  getResource(userUrl, (error, result) ->
    if error?
      throw new Error("Couldn't get data for user #{Configuration.user}")

    user = result.data
    if !user.email
      throw new Error("Need to be able to identify user by email")

    logger.debug("Removing all previous commits belonging to #{Configuration.user}")
    Commits.remove(user: Configuration.user)
    numCommits = 0
    getCommits(user, userUrl, start, (numCommits) ->
      taken = moment().diff(start, "seconds")
      logger.info("Inserted #{numCommits} commits for user #{Configuration.user} in #{taken} seconds")
    )
  )

Meteor.startup(->
  pollGitHub()
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably go a few different routes:

### Repos/Commits

Iterate through a users repos and getting commits for each

```
GET /users/:user/repos
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits
```

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories
http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository

### Push Events

```
GET /users/:user/events
```

http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent
http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-that-a-user-has-received

Anytime someone pushes, a push event is triggered, since to see a commit it needs to be pushed, if you look at a users push events, then you will see the associated commits!

Comment: I think the second route is the most useful, since you should be able to find all commits that way (so long as the user has pushed them). Have actually implemented this myself :)

Comment: good work! if you want me to add the code to my answer, message me (is that a thing?) or just comment it and i can add it for others who have your problem

Comment: I've pasted code to my question, it's a bit messy but will hopefully be helpful to others going down this path.